# Git "fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory" in existing repo

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

I have a repo on a network drive with a proper `.git` folder etc.

I am able to do everything I want with `git version 2.20.1.windows.1` on my machine (push/pull/branches etc.)

I am now trying to use the exact same folder on another machine with `git version 2.25.0.windows.1`.

The remote repo sits on AWS CodeCommit and I've verified that I can connect to it using the steps outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html) from the new machine.

No matter which git operation I try on the new machine, I get `fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory`. This includes trying to clone a repo into a new folder as well, not just operations on the existing repo/folder.

I can navigate to the folder and list its contents

[image]

Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: can windows list the contents of this directory?

Comment: yes i can navigate to it in PowerShell and list files within - have added a screenshot of it in the question

Comment: Note that this bug is specific to Windows (and also apparently involves longer path names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is linked to the actual version of git. Will install an older one.

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2480

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of GIT SCM, there is a security fix in v2.26.1. https://git-scm.com/download/win